# Structured bindings and mandatory copy elision

Tags: c++, c++17, copy-elision, structured-bindings

If you utilize structured bindings like so

```
auto [a, b, c] = std::make_tuple(1, 10.0, "string object"s);
```

then will the copies from the returned tuple be elided and the objects go straight into `a`, `b` and `c` or will the initializations be move constructions from the individual tuple elements?  I doubt that this would cause a copy to happen but I am not sure about whether the description of mandatory copy elision in the standard handles this case.

Comment: "will the copies from the returned tuple be elided and the objects go straight into a, b and c" No. "will the initializations be move constructions from the individual tuple elements" No.

Comment: @cpplearner then are they copied?

Answer (score 4):

As covered by [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41176491/1505939), the declaration is equivalent to:

```
auto e = std::make_tuple(1, 10.0, "string object"s);
int& a = get<0>(e);
double& b = get<1>(e);
std::string& c = get<2>(e);
```

except that there isn't a name `e`. The `get` function, in this context, yields an lvalue reference to the selected item.

In C++17, `auto name = prvalue;` [is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38043447/1505939) to declare an object called `name` of type `decltype(prvalue)` initialized with the prvalue expression -- there's no intermediate temporary that was elidable as in previous versions.

In other words, the `e` declaration behaves exactly the same as:

```
std::tuple<int, double, std::string> e {1, 10.0, "string object"s};
```

and then `a,b,c` are references to the elements of that tuple.

---

Note: The above explanation corresponds to the latest C++17 draft sources;  behaviour may change before C++17 is finalized of course.

Comment: In this example, `a`,`b`,`c` are `&&`s and `get` is called on the equivalent of `std::move(e)`.

Comment: @T.C. `e` is an lvalue, so `get<N>(e)` should be the version that takes lvalue reference and returns lvalue reference ?   (But even if you're right, the end result would be the same since a,b,c are also lvalues). [dcl.decomp/3] currently says "Otherwise, the initializer is `get<i>(e)`"

Comment: The wording here is pretty tricky. The key sentence is "In either case, `e` is an lvalue if the type of the entity `e` is an lvalue reference and an xvalue otherwise."

Comment: @T.C. OK, so the `e` in [dcl.decomp]/3 is not the same `e` as in /1 , which was specified to behave as-if by `auto e = prvalue;` (which would be an lvalue in all cases)

Comment: Right, it's not quite `e`-the-variable introduced in /1. Essentially this is core-language-style perfect forwarding.

Comment: In the lazy-evaluation proposal, having use of `c` invoke `get<2>(move(e))` at point of use, would mean that `string s = c;` would actually move out of `e` which seems unintuitive

Comment: Yes, they'll definitely have to tweak this part to make `c` remain an lvalue somehow.

Comment: @T.C. OK. I might leave my answer as-is then - even if it's technically xvalue version of `get`, the as-if result is the same; a,b,c should be lvalues referring to `e`