# How to enable structured bindings for a std::tuple wrapper class?

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, structured-bindings

I'm trying to implement a wrapper class for another class that has a private `std::tuple` member and enable structured bindings on the wrapper class. Here's the class with the private tuple:

```cpp
class widget {
  friend class wrap;
  std::tuple<int, double> m_tuple {1, 1.0};
};
```

Here's my attempt at the wrapper class after reading about how to enable structured bindings for custom types (e.g., [this post on devblogs.microsoft.com](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20201015-00/?p=104369)):

```cpp
class wrap {
public:
  wrap(widget& f) : m_tuple(f.m_tuple) {}

  // auto some_other_function();

  template<std::size_t Index>
  auto get() & -> std::tuple_element_t<Index, wrap>& {
    return std::get<Index>(m_tuple);
  }

  template<std::size_t Index>
  auto get() && -> std::tuple_element_t<Index, wrap>& {
    return std::get<Index>(m_tuple);
  }

  template<std::size_t Index>
  auto get() const& -> const std::tuple_element_t<Index, wrap>& {
    return std::get<Index>(m_tuple);
  }

  template<std::size_t Index>
  auto get() const&& -> const std::tuple_element_t<Index, wrap>& {
    return std::get<Index>(m_tuple);
  }

private:
  std::tuple<int, double>& m_tuple;
};
```

Here are the specialized `std::tuple_size` and `std::tuple_element` for `wrap`:

```cpp
namespace std {

template<>
struct tuple_size<wrap> : tuple_size<std::tuple<int, double>> {};

template<size_t Index>
struct tuple_element<Index, wrap> : tuple_element<Index, tuple<int, double>> {};
  
}  // namespace std
```

I'd like the following behavior:

```cpp
int main() {
  widget w;

  auto [i_copy, d_copy] = wrap(w);

  i_copy = 2;    // Does not change w.m_tuple because i_copy is a copy of std::get<0>(w.m_tuple).
  d_copy = 2.0;  // Does not change w.m_tuple because d_copy is a copy of std::get<1>(w.m_tuple).

  // w.m_tuple still holds {1, 1.0}.

  auto& [i_ref, d_ref] = wrap(w);

  i_ref = 2;   // Changes w.m_tuple because i_ref is a reference to std::get<0>(w.m_tuple).
  d_ref = 2.0; // Changes w.m_tuple because d_ref is a reference to std::get<1>(w.m_tuple).

  // w.m_tuple now holds {2, 2.0}.
}
```

But this doesn't even compile (tested with gcc 12.2.0 and clang 14.0.6). The error I get is

```
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘wrap&’ to an rvalue of type ‘wrap’
    |   auto& [i_ref, d_ref] = wrap(w);
```

Does the `non-const lvalue reference of type ‘wrap&’` refer to `auto& [i_ref, d_ref]` and the `rvalue of type ‘wrap’` to `wrap(w)`? Why are `i_ref` and `d_ref` not references to the integer and double of the tuple in `w`?

Edit: How can I implement a wrapper class that has the desired behavior?

Comment: It's for the same reason that prvalues don't bind to mutable reference, only const references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second example usage you have

```
auto& [i_ref, d_ref] = wrap(w);
```

**The `auto&` is the type for the invisible variable bound to the expression on the right side of the `=`** which is a temporary. It's like doing

```
wrap& wr = wrap(w);
```

I learned this [from T.C. in 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41176491/1013719), see that answer for all the relevant citations.

[We can produce the same error without any of your classes](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2o8dK01aUmirNPZw), just a tuple and an `auto&`

This code:

```
auto& [i, d] = std::tuple{1, 1.0};
```

produces this error:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:4:25: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'std::tuple<int, double>&' to an rvalue of type 'std::tuple<int, double>'
    4 |     auto& [i, d] = std::tuple{1, 1.0};
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

You can't bind a non-const lvalue reference to a temporary. If you change the line to

```
const auto& [i_ref, d_ref] = wrap(w);
```

Then you get through that line, but can't use `i_ref` or `d_ref` to modify anything because they're now aliases for the fields of a const object. If you want something you can modify then you'd have to give a name to the `wrap` object.

```
auto wrapped = wrap(w);
auto& [i_ref, d_ref] = wrapped;
i_ref = 2;
assert(std::get<0>(w.m_tuple) == 2);
```

[live here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8ZcBcSVY1dy4ch3w)

You could also make this work with an rvalue reference

```
auto&& [i_ref, d_ref] = wrap(w);
i_ref = 2;
assert(std::get<0>(w.m_tuple) == 2);
```

[live here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qDRhUrihvtD0MdzM)

Or no reference at all

```
auto [i_ref, d_ref] = wrap(w);
i_ref = 2;
assert(std::get<0>(w.m_tuple) == 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason that you can't use a function?

```cpp
class widget {
  friend std::tuple<int, double>& wrap(widget&);
  std::tuple<int, double> m_tuple {1, 1.0};
};

std::tuple<int, double>& wrap(widget& w) {
    return w.m_tuple;
}

int main() {
  widget w;
  auto [i_copy, d_copy] = wrap(w);
  auto& [i_ref, d_ref] = wrap(w);
}
```

Comment: The reason I wanted to use a class or struct was that I wanted the wrapper to enable other things as well, not just structured bindings.

Comment: If you use it as a temporary in a structured binding, which other things could you do here?